# JAVA: Why do I keep getting the error: cannot find symbol when I try to access another class file?

Tags: java, compilation

I have a class called Account which contains only banking methods such as create, withdraw, serviceFee, changeName, and deposit. There is no main method here.

Account is pretty long so here is a little snippet of it:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Account
{
private double balance;
private String name;
private long acctNum;
//Constructor -- initializes balance, owner, and account number
public Account(double initBal, String owner, long number)
{
balance = initBal;
name = owner;
acctNum = number;
}
```

My second class called ManageAccount contains the main method in which I create 2 bank accounts and do some activities such as depositing and withdrawing.

This is the simplified version of ManageAccount:

```
    package Account;
    import Account.*;

    public class ManageAccounts {
       public static void main(String[] args){
       Account acct1 = new Account(1000, "Sally", 1111);
       Account acct2 = new Account(500, "Joe", 1113);
       acct2.deposit(100);
       acct2.getBalance();
       acct1.withdraw(50);
    }
   }
```

I think there is something wrong with my import statement. I've done so much research but can't figure out how to fix it. Both the classes are in the same folder in my documents called Banking.

How can I get rid of this error? Do I need to make any changes to Account? I'm so confused..

Comment: Are they in different packages? Does your main class have a package statement?

Comment: My ManageAccount class has a package statement but Account does not..

Comment: I don't think they are in different packages...

Comment: Read the Java Tutorial - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/.  As you have written the code, they ARE in different packages!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Account class is not in the default package. Otherwise you cannot reference it within your import statement.

If you want to use

```
import Account.*;
```

than you have to move the Account class into the package 'Account'.

Comment: How can I move the Account class into 'Account' package? Sorry, I'm new and confused..

Comment: Depending on which IDE you are using you should be able to click and drag the .java files.

Comment: I'm using JGrasp which I don't think uses packages....pls correct me if i'm wrong!

Comment: If you do not use an IDE (you better should) than you have to create a folder 'Account' and move the class file there. Make sure that you use "package Account;" in the first line of the file.

Comment: In addition your ManageAccounts class also have to be in this Account Folder, if you use "package Account;" there.

Comment: Do I put "package Account;" as the first line in BOTH of my class files- so in both Account.java and ManageAccounts.java?

Comment: I see that I have 2 files for each class- one .class and one .java. Should I move all of these into the Account folder?

Comment: Please read the Tutorial @stephen-c linked to. Each Folder represents a package. So if both .java files should be in this package than both have to be in this folder.